# c# rest api only getting first value parameter list

Tags: c#, rest, http, get

I'm looking for a way to make my REST Api in C# so it will be able to work with request like this:

```
http://localhost:1234/api/Order/GetWithParam?orderIdString=4&orderIdString=7
```

Right now I have this in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesResponseType(typeof(Order), 200)]
[Route("api/Order/GetWithParam")]
public List<Order> GetDataWithParam(string orderIdString = null, DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null, string orderDescriptorsIdString = null)
    {
      ...
```

This works fine if I have one or zero arguments for my parameter:

```
http://localhost:1234/api/Order/GetWithParam?orderIdString=4
```

orderIdString will be equal to "4"

But if I send more than one argument for a parameter, only the first one will be taken :

```
http://localhost:1234/api/Order/GetWithParam?orderIdString=4&orderIdString=7
```

orderIdString will be equal to "4" ... but it should be equal to "4,7".

What am I missing?

-- EDIT --

I tried to change :

```
string orderIdString = null
```

to

```
string[] orderIdString
```

but now orderIdString is null even when there are parameters passed

```
http://localhost:1234/api/Order/GetWithParam?orderIdString=4&orderIdString=7
```

will give me orderIdString == null

Comment: You use .netCore or .Net framework fro this api?

Comment: @Sajid I'm using Microsoft.AspNet. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi v.5.2.7

Comment: Doesn't answer to my question, but for .Net framework this `public List<Order> GetDataWithParam([FromUri]string[] orderIdString, ...)` work well for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bind multiple parameter values you should make the type an array (`string[]`):

```
[HttpGet]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesResponseType(typeof(Order), 200)]
[Route("api/Order/GetWithParam")]
public List<Order> GetDataWithParam([FromQuery]string[] orderIdString = null, DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null, string orderDescriptorsIdString = null)
    {
      ...
```

Comment: I tried this, but now I'm not getting any parameters in orderIdString...

Comment: Did you add the [FromQuery] attribute?

Comment: Yes, same result with the  [FromQuery] attribute.

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong. Maybe have a read through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections but what I've put up should be working. Possibly the default value is confusing model binding but I wouldn't expect that to be the case.

Comment: I used another method and put all my orderIdString into one single string before sending it. I'll mark your answer as good. Thanks.